# Accessing 64-bit Registry in 32-bit application

Tags: java, registry

**Please do not mark this question as duplicate!**

I'm searching for a solution in java - **not C#** - and used the WinRegistry class.

I wrote a program that can readout a registry key. Now the problem: the java application is 32bit and I want to read the reg-keys from a windows 7 64bit-system. With this code windows will redirect my 32bit program to the 32bit section of the 64bit-registry (compare the real path with the comment in the code - Wow6432Node!).

```
// only access to "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
value = WinRegistry.readString(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "Citrix Login Service");
```

I deleted the try-catch-block so you are able to focus the real problem more better ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this now - thanks goes to Petrucio who posted this solution in 2012: [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/11854901#11854901).

E.g. - Read Operation:

```
try { 
  String value = WinRegistry.readString(WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "TestValue", WinRegistry.KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
  System.out.println(value);
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

I hope that is usefully for someone.

Comment: thank you very much. Your research saved me a lot of time and frustration

Comment: Appreciate! Got same trouble.